# How to periodically wake and check status in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want my app to periodically wake and check a status, but burn minimal cycles between wake ups. Is the a Core call for this or an accepted design pattern?

Comment: can you be specific about what you want do do when you "check status" at all? and is ios7-only acceptable to you? If so the options available are broader.

Comment: @RobP I would like to check the battery level.  I would prefer older versions of iOS also, but am interested in the trade offs.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to ios7, apps could only ask for execution cycles in background for a handful of purposes (e.g. playing sound or getting location updates). While they added more options in ios7, like periodically fetching data from a server, I'm still not clear there is a way to do this. (It's also a bit difficult for me to imagine why your app cares about battery if it isn't running, but maybe that is my failure of imagination.) Recommend reading **Background Execution and Multitasking** in [the AppleDocs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20).